# doxygen and C# Xml comments conflict on specifying symbols

Tags: visual-studio-2019, doxygen

I have a C# project (VS2019) with XML-style documentation comments.
Documentation is generated with doxygen.

Numerous comments must include the trademark symbol. I'd like this to show up correctly in VS2019 and in the generated docs.

Using `&trade;` (per HTML) works with doxygen, but fails in VS2019 (it produces CS1570 during compilation, and VS shows empty documentation).

Using `&#8482;` (per XML) works within VS2019, but fails in the doxygen-generated docs.
It shows up as  `&amp;#8482;`  in the raw HTML.

This is all sort of expected, as it's XML vs HTML.
Is there a way to get VS2019 & doxygen to cooperate better?
Preferably without having to convert all the doc-comments to doxygen-style.